# How exactly does scipy.optimize's minimize function work?

Tags: python, lambda, minimize, calculus

I've been looking through the minimize function declaration files, and I am really confused as to how the function works. So for example, if I have something like this:

```
import numpy as np
from scipy.integrate import quad
from scipy.optimize import minimize
encoderdistance = 2.53141952655
Dx = lambda t: -3.05 * np.sin(t)
Dy = lambda t: 2.23 * np.cos(t)
def func(x): return np.sqrt(Dx(x)**2 + Dy(x)**2)
print minimize(lambda x: abs(quad(func, 0, x)[0] - encoderdistance), 1).x
print minimize(lambda x: abs(4.24561823393 - encoderdistance), 1).x
```

the second print statement at the bottom will yield a different result than the one on the top even though I subbed out the quad function for the value it produced. If this is due to the lambda x part, can you explain how that affects that line of code exactly? Also, how would you type the second to last line into a calculator such as wolfram alpha? Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The optimizer needs a function to minimize -- that's what the `lambda x:` is about.

In the second-to-last line, you're asking the optimizer to find a value of x such that the integral from 0 to x of func(x) is close to encoderdistance.

In the last line, the function to be minimized in your last line is just a scalar value, with no dependency on x, and the optimizer is bailing out because it can't change that.

Answer (score 1):

How `scipy.minimize` works is described [here](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.optimize.minimize.html) but that isn't your issue. You have two lambda functions that are definitely not the same:

```
lambda x: abs(quad(func, 0, x)[0] - encoderdistance)
lambda x: abs(4.24561823393 - encoderdistance)
```

The first is a 'V'-shaped function while the second is a horizontal line. `scipy` finds the minimum of the 'V' at about 1.02 and cannot perform any minimization on a horizontal line so it returns your initial guess: 1.

Answer (score 0):

Here is how you could do it in Mathematica:

```
Dx[t_] := -3.05*Sin[t]
Dy[t_] := 2.23*Cos[t]
func[x_] := Sqrt[Dx[x]^2 + Dy[x]^2]
encoderdistance = 2.53141952655;
fmin[x_?NumberQ] := 
 Abs[NIntegrate[func[t], {t, 0, x}] - encoderdistance]
NMinimize[fmin[x], x][[2]][[1]][[2]]
```

With regard to your first question, in statement:

```
print minimize(lambda x: abs(4.24561823393 - encoderdistance), 1).x
```

your lambda function is a constant *independent of the argument* `x`. `minimize` quits immediately after observing that the function does not decrease after several variations of the argument.